# When is $A[y]/(f(y))$ isomorphic to $A[a]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

To elaborate a bit, $A$ is an integral domain, $f$ is a monic irreducible polynomial and $a$ is a root of $f$. $A[a]$ is the smallest subring of $\overline{\mathrm{Quot}(A)}$ (*Quot* denotes the field of fractions) that contains $A$ and $a$ while $(f)$ is the ideal generated by $f$.

One can immediately define $F:A[y]\to A[a]$ by the rule $F(g(y))\mapsto g(a)$. Everything seems to work until you come to prove that $\ker F=(f(y))$. In other cases, the so-called "modern version" of Gauss's lemma can yield the result but now $A$ is not a UFD! I am not aware of any other post-modern version of that lemma that works in general domains.

The context under which this question arose is the first paragraph of page 99 of D. Lorenzini's book "Invitation to arithmetic geometry" where it is stated that the two rings are isomorphic.

Comment: What is $\overline A$? And is $y$ just a polynomial indeterminate?

Comment: $\bar{A}$ was wrong, I corrected it. Yes.

Comment: Still, what does the overline mean?

Comment: It means the algebraic closure; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure 
Don't make me post the integral domain page too

Comment: I see. The key is that $f$ is monic. Now let $g \in \ker F$. Then, we can divide $g$ by $f$ with remainder (since $f$ is monic!); i.e., there exist (unique) polynomials $q, r \in A\left[y\right]$ such that $g = qf + r$ and $\deg r < \deg f$. From $g \in \ker F$ and $f \in \ker F$, it thus follows that $r \in \ker F$. In other words, $r\left(a\right) = 0$. But the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\operatorname{quot}\left(A\right)$ is $f$. This minimal polynomial must divide $r$ over $\operatorname{quot}\left(A\right)$ (since $r\left(a\right) = 0$). Since $\deg r < \deg f$, this yields $r=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that division holds over arbitrary rings provided that the leading coef. is invertible (like in our case). Write it as an aswer so I can accept if you like.